# Speech to text conversion php,javascript or flash online

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, speech-recognition

I know php well and I use javascript and jquery but I don't seem to know how to make a speech to text conversion with them though, but i do know that there are many flash speech recognition api's around but I would like a faster, I would like a script for this that can accurately use your voice and convert it into text. 
Thank you very Much,
Anonymous.

Comment: I'd assume that one is impossible. I don't know any library to analyse sounds for PHP.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say its impossible, just that any sane developer wouldn't choose PHP or JavaScript as candidates for doing speech recognition

Comment: A JS speech recognition program may well be impossible.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to do speech recognition from an html page, you might want to look at some other alternatives. Chrome supports speech recognition for text input. See http://slides.html5rocks.com/#speech-input and http://www.filosophy.org/2011/03/talking-to-the-web-the-basics-of-html5-speech-input/.

These use the following tag for speech recognition:

```
<input type=”text” speech x-webkit-speech />
```

I believe Chrome is the only browser that currently supports this. http://tomlerendu.com/tutorial/how-to-use-html-5-speech-input/ has a good example and shows

```
if( document.createElement('input').webkitSpeech==undefined )
{
  //no speech support
}
```

as a means to test if speech recognition is supported.

Historically, there have been other approaches. Opera implemented a different solution, but it appears they are no longer supporting it - http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/getting-to-know-voice/.

Another approach that has been used is to use a java applet or flash app that communicates with a speech recognition back end. WAMI is a good example of this - http://wami.csail.mit.edu/. These approaches use a rich client (Java or Flash or other plug in) to capture speech and send it to a server or some local speech engine for processing.

Answer (score 1):

In html 5 trere is a tag you can do it with that..

Read:
[link1](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-htmlspeech/2011Feb/att-0020/api-draft.html)
[link2](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-speech-input-fields/)

Comment: First link is of w3c.org which can't be dead..okay..And for second link I hace included that html5 has tag to do so..

Comment: And I wonder why people are saying its impossible, don't we see google has a for the same, then why can't one think of having..

Comment: Voice recognition is possible, *pokes SIRI*, and has been going on for quite awhile. (I believe over ten years ago) the thing is it can never be *PERFECT*, do to user errors. Also the old ones were not written in PHP, mainly C or C++ or maybe Java.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at speechapi.com and build yourself what you need but if its the other way around;text to speech,speak.js will do.

Hope that helps.