# Voice Recognition in PHP?

Tags: php, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, audio

I am looking for Voice Recognition in PHP.

I have a lot of wav files (10-15 seconds) and I would like  Voice Recognition to recognise 1 or 2 words from each wav file and then flag it to database or csv.

All the files have the same voice and accent (same person lol)

Example pseudocode:

```
$voice = new play('file.wav');
$result = $voice->recognise("Good Morning");
if ($result) { 
  echo "Matched Good Morning"; 
  //flag to database or csv
 } else { 
  echo "No match found";
 }
```

Which PHP Voice Recognition library can do this?

Comment: Didn't even know that WAS possible in PHP?

Comment: "Why would someone do that in PHP" the above question been tagged in php ...so refrain from using negative comments if you can't do hands up thankfully no downgrade was there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP doesn't have this functionality built in but there are APIs available for this [Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) is one.

Answer (score 0):

Similar questions have been asked before. You might want to see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6351055/90236 to start your search for a speech engine.

There have also been a few questions regarding uses Php for speech recognition in web pages. Doesn't seem like your doing that, but it is Php - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8717077/90236

Answer (score 0):

You can use our voice recognition api in rapidapi for free, php code sample is also available.
Available for English and French.
Use the following link:
https://rapidapi.com/user/hivoicy-vxmKOG2vl